# webservice that exposes a method which takes an Object as a parameter

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am working JAX-WS web service. I need to write a web service that exposes a method which takes an Object as a parameter. Hence, the client invoking this web service can pass any type of object including user defined class objects. For e.g.:

```
public String invokeMe(Ojbect obj);
```

From Client web service: I am passing my user defined class object as a parameter to the exposed method.

```
Pitta obj = new Pitta(); //Pitta is the name of a class.
```

e.g.:

```
String result = invokeMe(obj);
```

Anyone could please help me out.

Comment: Could you clarify why you would you want to pass an arbitrary object to invokeMe(). Even if this did work, your web service would probably not be able to do anything meaningful with what you sent up since it would just be an instance of Object.

Answer (score 2):

You can not create a `JAX-WS` web method which takes an `java.lang.Object` as a parameter. `JAX-WS` is based on `JAXB` so you can pass only `JAXB` supported types as a web method parameters. `java.lang.Object` is not JAXB supported type.

What I suggest is to create an object and make it parent to all other objects that could possibly be passed as parameters to your web method. For e.g.:

```
public class ParentObj {...}

public class WebParam1 extends ParentObj {...}

public class WebParam2 extends ParentObj {...}

public class WebParam3 extends ParentObj {...}
```

and the method:

```
public void someMethod(ParentObj obj) {...}
```

Then you'll be able to pass `WebParam1`, `WebParam2`, `WebParam3`.

Of course don't forget annotations if you are using `Java-First` approach. If `WSDL-FIRST`: write `XSD` representing your objects.